# Concerned about malicious libraries in my project

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, libraries

So for a while now I have been building my virtual assistant in python which has required the use of several external libraries. I have also been converting the scripts to an exe using pyinstaller. However only the other day, windows defender told me that there was something wrong which was only affecting the exe file I had created

It said `Trojan: Win32/Wacatac.C!ml`

I simply don't understand how this was only flagged up now and not before considering I have been working on this project for over a month now.

Here is a list of the modules I have used:

newsapi, Wikipedia, threading, autocorrect, random, time,email, calendar, datetime, math, sys, webbrowser, pyttsx3, io, speech_recognition,imaplib, pickle, wmi, docx, comtypes, googletrans, qhue, pyowm, ast, pyaudio, pycaw, tkinter, smtplib, email, bs4, requests

Comment: Hello! It's easier to get answers when you post the code directly instead of a photo of it.

Comment: if you google `pyinstaller false positive` you will find a lot information, incl. here on SO. Most likely that is the case here too

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a false positive. There's nothing malicious about your third-party modules, the issue has to do with PyInstaller.

PyInstaller comes with pre-compiled bootloader binaries. Since many actual amateur viruses are written in Python, and then converted to executables using PyInstaller, most anti-virus software will flag those pre-compiled bootloader binaries as being malicious. The only real solution is to compile your own bootloader.

Comment: Thanks, that's a huge sigh of relief.

Answer (score 1):

False positive? You mention "the use of several external libraries." Not sure how from that info one can be sure it's a false positive. Despite other answers to the contrary, unless you have personally looked at the code... you don't.

PyPI, the "official" repository, has on many occasions, and as recently as Dec 2019, been found to have been serving up malware long before such malware was discovered. See e.g. https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/python-package-installation-can-trigger-malicious-code/, https://www.zdnet.com/article/two-malicious-python-libraries-removed-from-pypi/.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I checked over the modules and I haven't used any of those modules. My only concern was "urllib" and the malicious library "urlib"

Comment: Glad none you used were at issue. FYI I've updated the second link in my answer which describes this (it originally was erroneously pointing to a different article)

Answer (score 1):

As @Paul M. explained it is a false positive and the bootloader needs to be locally compiled. This may be out of scope to add another answer to this but thought it would be helpful to anyone wondering how to recompile the ***pyinstaller*** bootloaders.

1. Verify the correct windows compiler is installed here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers
2. Install PyInstaller the manual method by downloading the latest release source code here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases

   1. Depending on if PyInstaller is already installed with Pip you may need to uninstall it: `python.exe -m pip uninstall pyinstaller`
   2. Unzip wherever and navigate to the bootloader directory in PyInstaller.
   3. Run either one of the commands to build for your architecture:

      ```
      python.exe ./waf all --target-arch=32bit
      ```

      OR

      ```
      python.exe ./waf all --target-arch=64bit
      ```
   4. Navigate to the root PyInstaller Directory

      ```
      python.exe setup.py install
      ```
   5. Rerun original pyinstaller command to package python to exe.

FYI I've had to redo this twice now, I'm not sure if it has to do with deploying these portable executables to other windows machine and windows defender flagging it and later pushing the signature in an update or what the deal is but recompiling the bootloader seems to work.